# Cannot drop user due to object ownership in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to drop user `foo` from an AWS Redshift db

```
DROP USER foo;
ERROR:  user "foo" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  1 object in database bar
1 object in database zoo
1 object in database barzoo
```

How can I find the ONE object on each db that causes the problem?

Answer (score 1):

AWSLABS does a great job with this type of utility.  See https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_find_dropuser_objs.sql

Comment: does this need to run on each databases on the Redshift cluster?

Comment: Likely yes.  You don't get cross-db queries unless you are in a cluster with RA3 nodes.  In this case you need to run against all dbs separately AFAIK.  If you are on RA3 nodes then you may be able to rewrite the admin query to be cross db aware but I expect it will be easier to run against dbs individually.